# Why does GMail break inline (CSS) styles for an email with minified markup/HTML using quote-printable encoding?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, minify

I had an email that was getting clipped by GMail (around 120Kb in size — according to http://www.adestra.com/avoid-gmail-clipping-emails/, GMail starts clippping the messages at 102Kb)

[image: GMail clipping emails]

To reduce the email size, I decided to try out both [django-htmlmin](https://github.com/cobrateam/django-htmlmin) and plain ol' `re.sub(r'\n\s*(\S)', r'\1', email_html_content)` (Modifying markup using regex is a discussion for another day). Both these techniques resulted in 30%+ reduction in email size, but both solutions broke the rendering in GMail. When inspecting the broken design using Dev Tools, it seems some of the elements are not getting any inline styles, apparently at random.

[image: Element in GMail without any inline styles]

However, when I clicked on 'Show Original' to view the raw email, I'm seeing inline styles for the element.

[image: Inline styles visible in the raw email]

When checking the raw email, I saw that it is encoded using the `quote-printable` format. Which means, even though my entire email is just 1 line when minified, line breaks (`=` in quote-printable format) are inserted automatically, as is visible in the picture above. Some of these line breaks (`=` characters at the end of the line) appear mid-attribute values, but the email client seems to be ignoring these breaks and I don't think they are cause of the broken rendering (even my original email with unminified markup had such line breaks, and it was being rendered fine — according to my reading, it the email spec that suggests lines have a maximum limit of 78(?) characters).

Another pattern I saw in the raw email code was after a chunk of lines (each delimited by a `=`), there seems to be a paragraph that is delimited by a `=0D` character. Each paragraph is not the same size and I'm cannot find any source on why these characters are being inserted in a one-line, minified markup email. The paragraph pattern can be seen in the image below:

[image: random paragraphs delimited by <code>=0D</code> character]

Even this character is appearing mid-attribute value for certain tags and I think this might be the reason the rendering is breaking. I got the rendering working again by using `re.sub(r'\n\s*(\S)', r'\n\1', email_body)` instead of `re.sub(r'\n\s*(\S)', r'\1', email_body)` — i.e. each tag (opening or closing) on a separate line instead of mashing up everything in just one line. This increased the size of the email, but got rid of the `=0D` characters from appearing mid-attribute value. Now it is at the end of each line and the email is rendering fine.

[image: With each tag on a separate line]

So, my question is, how do I minify my email HTML and still produce an unbroken rendering within email clients? What is causing the broken rendering and how may I go about fixing it?

Comment: Why are you encoding carriage return signes?! What purpose does it serve?! Remove them!! Why do you encode equal sign? it's perfectly valid to use literal = instead! You'll use less space if you use literals.

Comment: @klarki Correct me if I'm wrong, but that's a valid encoding widely used by email clients. This encoding is done automatically by my transaction email service (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)

Comment: it is valid in form, but it makes no sense to use encoded carriage return sign in these places, and equal signs as well. What's the point if you can just use literal carriage returns and equal signs.

You could also encode every single ascii char, for example each 'a' to '=61' and it would be still valid, but why?! Quoted printable is meant to encode chars from OUTSIDE ascii table. Like national characters ąęśćźń etc.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon exactly the same problem, although I wasn't using any custom regex patterns for minifying html.

Turns out, the problem is that some html parsers (including gmail) have limitations for the line length of the html that is being sent.

[This article](http://edmdesigner.com/blog/how-to-minify-your-html-email) explains nicely what's going on. Just like you noticed the html parsers have their own ways of splitting long lines and creating new line breaks. And these ways fail.

So the solution is to minify you html emails in a way that keeps all your lines not longer than a specific length.

I've successfully used this [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) (actually I used [gulp-htmlmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlmin) which uses the "html-minifier") passing `{ maxLineLength: 996 }` as an option.

The emails are no longer broken :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that don't work in one or another email client and unfortunately this is much more common than in the browser world. They are not supported as security precautions or because email client developers were lazy to implement their support.

I recommend to read https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ as a starting point to ensure that your email is going to be rendered correctly.

Comment: I agree. However, the email renders fine with inline styles from the same stylesheet when it is not minified (or as I mentioned in the answer, minified with just one tag on each line). It's the minification of the markup to just _one_ line that is breaking the rendering (with the same stylesheet — no changes there). I'm guessing that points to it not being a CSS issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what is causing your problems.

In your file you have carriage return line feed line endings.

By doing `re.sub(r'\n\s*(\S)', r'\1', email_html_content)` you remove the line feeds but leave carriage returns intact, which in return get encoded in quoted printable encoding (=0D). These chars are causing your problems. This is also why using  `re.sub(r'\n\s*(\S)', r'\n\1', email_body)` works. The problems are caused by sole carriage return signs while carriage return - line feed pairs work ok.

If I understand your intention correctly to remove unnecessary white space you should modify the code to strip carriage return signs as well:

```
re.sub(r'\r\n\s*(\S)', r'\1', email_html_content)
```

This should reduce space and will not cause problems with interpreting the css file.

With that said, wouldn't it be better to improve the regex to something like that:

```
re.sub(r'\s*\r\n\s*', r'', email_html_content)
```

This works in this way: find any number of white space, carriage return line feed pair and any number of white space, and remove them, instead of find carriage return line feed pair, any number of white space and one non white space char and replace it with the char.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I used the regex `\s*\r?\n\r?\s*` (based on your suggestion, yet more liberal) to minify the entire email into one line but still no luck. The random `=0D` still appear in my emails, delimiting the wall of text into random paragraphs — the rendering is still broken.

Comment: @GauravDadhania, the CR characters don't appear random to me.  It looks like they are added as line breaks when the lines get too longer. 

Maybe you cannot avoid having some breaks being added in.  If so, strip out the breaks as long as your current line length is < whatever the magic value is.